# Transaction and multiple queries via ODBC

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, odbc

I have an interface, firing multiple SQL queries via an ODBC connection.

Those queries create functions, stored procedures, execute stored procedures and so on.

If one of them fails, I'd like a complete rollback to start.

The simple plan to query a `begin transaction` and a `commit transaction` at end leads to a runtime error after `begin transaction`, because no commit is fired at this time.

Is there a possibility to put a transaction block around the bunch of queries?

Comment: Why do you need transactions around queries, supposedly they are readonly ? or are there any side effects to reading the data ?

Comment: it's not just about reading data; tables and SPs are created, functions executed and so on. it's all about integrating a complex addon and if one of the queries fired throws an exception, i want to remove all created objects to get back to zero.
i've edited question about these information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.
I assume you mean to made an Insert or Update kinds of sql statements (not a select query).
Before you made this kind of action you should remember to run the queries in a single transaction ONLY if they dont have relation with the new data you set between the queries. this because the new data is not commited yet so you cannot use is in the next statement.

here is a code the runs a set of commands by using transaction.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute commands with an open SQL connection.
    /// Note: To execute a stored procedure send to useTransaction parameter false value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">An opened SqlConnection</param>
    /// <param name="commands">A string array of the requested commands to execute</param>
    /// <param name="useTransaction">true if to force transaction, false to execute the commands without transaction</param>
    /// <returns>true for success, otherwise false</returns>
    public static bool ExecuteSqlCommands(SqlConnection connection, string[] commands, bool useTransaction)
    {
        bool bStatus = false;

        string[] lines = commands; // regex.Split(sql);

        SqlTransaction transaction = null;
        if (useTransaction)
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            if (useTransaction)
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = line;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException e)
                    {
                        string msg = e.Message;
                        if (useTransaction)
                            transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            bStatus = true;
        }
        if (bStatus && useTransaction)
            transaction.Commit();

        return bStatus;
    }
```